# foreach issue select form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have hit a brick wall on my codeigniter project.

I can update my theme/template to database via select form in my settings. I can do that OK and the themes/templates show up OK in the select form.

But the `$templates == $config_template` not showing the current theme/template that is selected.

**I am not to sure what to add for the controller part and the model to be able to make it display current theme/template from database as first one.**

Here is what I have done so far.

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings extends MX_Controller {

   public function index() {

    $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));

        $data['action'] = site_url('admin/settings');

        $data['logout'] = site_url('admin/logout');

        $data['home'] = site_url('admin/dashboard');

        $data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/dashboard');

        $this->load->model('admin/setting/model_setting_store');

        $this->model_setting_store->config_template();

        $data['templates'] = array();

        $directories = glob(APPPATH . 'modules/catalog/views/theme/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            $data['templates'][] = basename($directory);
        }


        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_meta_title', 'Website Title');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_meta_description', 'Description');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_meta_keyword', 'Keywords');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('config_template', 'Template');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        return $this->load->view('setting/settings', $data);

    } else {

        redirect('admin/dashboard');

    }

   }

}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class Model_setting_store extends CI_Model {

    function config_template() {
        $data = array(
            'setting_id' => "10",
            'website_id' => "0",
            'group' => "config",
            'key' => "config_template",
            'value' => $this->input->post('config_template')
        );

        $this->db->update('setting', $data);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-setting" class="form-horizontal">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab-general" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_general;?></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-store" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_store; ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-server" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $tab_server; ?></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-general"></div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-store">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-template"><?php echo $entry_template; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select name="config_template" id="input-template" class="form-control">
<?php foreach ($templates as $template) { ?>
<?php if ($template == $config_template) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template; ?>"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`ing the variables you're comparing?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't exactly tested it out but you can try this out with `set_select` using the [Form Helper.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
<select name="config_template" id="input-template" class="form-control">
<?php foreach( $templates as $template ): ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $template; ?>" <?php echo set_select('config_template', $template, $template == $config_template ? TRUE : FALSE); ?>><?php echo $template; ?></option>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**Edit:** I actually don't see where you've set `$config_template` exactly. I only see it referenced in the model as `$data['value']` or what would be `$value` in the view.